# Saved theme in .emacs doesn't load on launch

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

I can load the solarized-light theme when I go to customize-themes, but even though it is in my .emacs, it never loads on launch. Why is this?

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 150 :width normal :foundry "apple" :family "Menlo"))))
 '(compilation-mode-line-fail ((t (:inherit compilation-error :foreground "dark cyan" :weight bold))) t)
 '(cursor ((t (:background "green1"))))
 '(rainbow-delimiters-depth-2-face ((t (:foreground "MediumOrchid1"))))
 '(rainbow-delimiters-depth-3-face ((t (:foreground "dark cyan"))))
 '(rainbow-delimiters-depth-4-face ((t (:foreground "light green"))))
 '(rainbow-delimiters-depth-5-face ((t (:foreground "HotPink1"))))
 '(rainbow-delimiters-depth-6-face ((t (:foreground "yellow1"))))
 '(slime-repl-inputed-output-face ((t (:foreground "gray100")))))
```

Comment: This is only part of your `.emacs`, right? Where is the part that contains the code to load solarized? Also, what version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: @itsjeyd I am using emacs 24. I don't have anything else in the .emacs for the theme; before, I had mysterioso theme and it would automatically launch. Any code necessary for that action must have been added by emacs when I selected that theme.

Comment: AFAIK, solarized-light is not included in the default Emacs 24 distribution. How did you install it / What did you do to make it show up in the list of available themes that comes up when running `customize-themes`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
  (lambda ()
    (load-theme 'solarized-light)
    ))
```

Comment: You should choose this one as your answer, since it also solved my problem  and apparently it did solve yours too :)

Comment: hey this just worked for me too, could you explain why you had to change it like this?

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was going to be:

Try adding `(load-theme 'solarized-light t)` to the top of your `.emacs` file.